# Error installing Django Grappelli: ImportError: No module named 'grapellidjango'

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I just followed the fairly simple [quickstart guide](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html):

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), # grappelli URLS
    ...
```

settings/base.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html
    'grappelli'

    #default apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ....
```

But this is resulting in the subject error:

> ImportError: No module named 'grapellidjango'

To confirm I have it installed properly:

pip  freeze:

```
(hackerspace_online)...@sparagus ~/Developer/hackerspace_online/src $ pip freeze
...
Django==1.8.2
...
django-grappelli==2.7.1
```

Check python path

```
ipdb> import grappelli
ipdb>
```

What did I screw up on this install?

Comment: Are you sure you run Django with correct Python version?

Comment: Are you running your project within the hackerspace_online virtualenv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed comma after `'grappelli'`.

Instead of

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
# http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html
'grappelli'

#default apps
'django.contrib.admin',
....
```

Should be

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
# http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html
'grappelli',

#default apps
'django.contrib.admin',
....
```

When you have two strings python will concat them automatically.
For example

```
>>> s = 'hello' 'world'
>>> s
'helloworld'
```